# Get document for each user from Firestore Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Im trying to get document for each user login to his account , i have two collections in Firestore one called ( firstName ) and the second one called ( lastName ) and i want from user 1 to get ( firstName ) collection only and user number 2 to get ( lastName ) collection only.

i tried with if statement but it doesn't work with me .

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class namesTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var names: UITableView!
var db: Firestore!
var firstName = [String]()
var lastName = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    names.register(UINib(nibName: "Order1TableViewCell", bundle: nil) , forCellReuseIdentifier: "order")
    
    names.dataSource = self
    names.delegate = self
    
    db = Firestore.firestore()

   

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    guard let viewController1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login") as? logInViewController else{return}        
   viewController1.userNameField?.delegate = self

 
    if viewController1.userNameField?.text == “1@1.com" {
     loadData1()
    }

    if viewController1.userNameField?.text == “2@2.com” {
     loadData2()
    }
    
       

func loadData1() {
    db.collection("firstName").getDocuments()
    {
        (querySnapshot, err) in
        
        if let err = err
        {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
        }
        else
        {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                
                self.firstName.append(document.get("firstname") as? String ?? "")
                self.lastName.append(document.get("lastname") as? String ?? "")
            }
        }
        self.names.reloadData()
    }
}




func loadData2() {
    db.collection("lastName").getDocuments()
    {
        (querySnapshot, err) in
        
        if let err = err
        {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
        }
        else
        {
            
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                self.firstName.append(document.get("firstname") as? String ?? "")
                self.lastName.append(document.get("lastname") as? String ?? "")
            }
        }
        self.names.reloadData()
    }
}
}
```

this is logInViewController code

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class logInViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var userNameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passwordField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var logInButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    logInButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    userNameField.delegate = self
    passwordField.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


@IBAction func logInButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: (userNameField.text ?? ""), password: (passwordField.text ?? "")) { (result, error) in
              if let _eror = error{
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                               let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                               alert.addAction(okAction)
                               self.present(alert,animated: true)
                  print(_eror.localizedDescription)
              }else{
                  if let _res = result{
                      print(_res)
                  }
                
                
               
                
        
                
                let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "order1") as! namesTableViewController
                self.navigationController!.pushViewController(VC1, animated: true)
                
                
                
                
              }
          }
 }


}
```

this is fire store structure
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcTb4.png)

Comment: please share firestore collection structure

Comment: @Babar i updated my code please check it

Comment: Please upload the code of firstViewController

Comment: Add the code IN you wrote in logInViewController, you just added my solution so far

Comment: @LucaSfragara i added it , please check

Comment: why are you making such a weird data model? why a collection for firstName and another for lastName? much better is to included all this info in one collection like "users" and every document in it represent a single user. then you can get the document of the signed in user by using the [auth.Currentuser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#currentuser)

Comment: How can it work? You are checking the value of  the textfield just after presenting the VC that contains. The text will just be empty

Comment: And I would really change the overall approach, as the other comment says, why would you have such a firestore structure

Answer (score 0):

Be careful by doing `let view1 = firstViewController()` you are not grabbing the correct instance of `firstViewController` but one you just created. `User.text` therefore won't be set. You need to grab the right instance of it, if you are using storyboard you can do:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "nameofstoryboard", bundle: nil)
guard let viewController1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myIdentifier") as? firstViewController else{return} //set VC Identifier in Storyboard identity inspector
```

Then you can check the `User` property with `if-statement`

Comment: Please upload the full code in your question